# JSP database connection and data insert

Tags: sql, jsp

I am trying to connect to the database and insert only one value in the database using JSP. i have made table `category` with 2 columns namely `Category_id` and `Category_name`, where  `Category_id` is auto increment . so i want to insert only category name into the table. the problem is , i am not able to insert.
the following the code i have written:

```
String cname = request.getParameter("cname");
try{
         // Register JDBC driver
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

         // Open a connection
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/infoshare", "root", "");

         // Execute SQL query
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

         String sql;
         sql = "INSERT INTO catagory(Catagory_name) VALUES("+cname+")";

          //ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         //out.print(cname);

         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
         out.print("<h1>Hello</h1>");

         // Clean-up environment
         //rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         //Handle errors for JDBC
         se.printStackTrace();
      }catch(Exception e){
         //Handle errors for Class.forName
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: no error message, it prints the name but does not prints hello as shown in the code above

Comment: is it missing single quote (i.e. ') in SQL?

Comment: sql= "insert into category(Category_name) values('"+cname+"')";                 I tried this one also but isn't working

Comment: Can you change the statement " se.printStackTrace();" to "out.print(se.getMessage());"?

It will print the error message to browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several times, i got the answer as follows:

```
 String cname = request.getParameter("cname");
 String cstatus = request.getParameter("cstatus");
try{
         // Register JDBC driver
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

         // Open a connection
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/infoshare", "root", "");

         // Execute SQL query
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         //
        String sql;
        sql = "INSERT INTO category(Category_name,status) values('"+cname+"','"+cstatus+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        // ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         response.sendRedirect("add_category.jsp");         

         // Clean-up environment
        //rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         //Handle errors for JDBC
         se.printStackTrace();
      }catch(Exception e){
         //Handle errors for Class.forName
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```